# how to interpolate a numpy array with linear interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which has the following shape: (1, 128, 160, 1).

Now, I have an image which has the shape: (200, 200).

So, I do the following:

```
orig = np.random.rand(1, 128, 160, 1)
orig = np.squeeze(orig)
```

Now, what I want to do is take my original array and interpolate it to be of the same size as the input image i.e. `(200, 200)` using linear interpolation. I think I have to specify the grid on which the numpy array should be evaluated but I am unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you meant *bilinear* interpolation – [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Ahhhh ok, so the sampling grid can just be defined simply as a meshed grid or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` like this:

```
from scipy import interpolate

# Make a fake image - you can use yours.
image = np.ones((200,200))

# Make your orig array (skipping the extra dimensions).
orig = np.random.rand(128, 160)

# Make its coordinates; x is horizontal.
x = np.linspace(0, image.shape[1], orig.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(0, image.shape[0], orig.shape[0])

# Make the interpolator function.
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, orig, kind='linear')

# Construct the new coordinate arrays.
x_new = np.arange(0, image.shape[1])
y_new = np.arange(0, image.shape[0])

# Do the interpolation.
new_orig = f(x_new, y_new)
```

Note the -1 adjustment to the coordinate range when forming `x` and `y`. This ensures that the image coordinates go from 0 to 199 inclusive.