# Resample Numpy 2D array to arbitrary new size

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a 2d numpy array (611,1024) of floats that I need to resize to 256,256. I'm trying to use [interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

Here is what I've tried (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126099/5495698)):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

arr = np.random.random((611,1024))

W, H = arr.shape[:2]
new_W, new_H = (256,256)
xrange = lambda x: np.linspace(0, 1, x)

f = interpolate.interp2d(xrange(W), xrange(H), arr, kind="linear")
new_arr = f(xrange(new_W), xrange(new_H))
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-61-90f66cfeb2d9> in <module>
      5 xrange = lambda x: np.linspace(0, 1, x)
      6 
----> 7 f = interpolate.interp2d(xrange(W), xrange(H), img, kind="linear")
      8 new_arr = f(xrange(new_W), xrange(new_H))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py in __init__(self, x, y, z, kind, copy, bounds_error, fill_value)
    207             if z.ndim == 2:
    208                 if z.shape != (len(y), len(x)):
--> 209                     raise ValueError("When on a regular grid with x.size = m "
    210                                      "and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z "
    211                                      "must have shape (n, m)")

ValueError: When on a regular grid with x.size = m and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z must have shape (n, m)
```

This answer helped me: [how to interpolate a numpy array with linear interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373964/how-to-interpolate-a-numpy-array-with-linear-interpolation)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you try swapping xrange(W) and xrange(H)?

Comment: that fixed it. thanks.